# AngularJS $routeParams / service not fetching data from JSON

Tags: angularjs, json, route-provider, routeparams

On test-detail.html page (partial view), data from respective json files are not fetched/displayed, i.e. the controller TestDetailCtrl is called in test-detail.html (as can be seen on a working alert button), but params curly brackets in view (test-detail.html) are empty.
However ListController for test-list.html works and fetches the tests.json.

File structure:

- index.html
- (tests)

  - tests.json (content correctly displayed in test-list.html)
  - a.json
  - b.json
- (js)
- (partials)
- (css)

partials/test-list.html:

```
<form action="" data-ng-repeat="test in tests | orderBy:orderProp">
        <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="item.selected" data-ng-change="change(item)"> 
            <a href="#/tests/{{test.id}}">
                <img data-ng-src="{{test.imageUrl}}" alt="{{test.name}}" class="test-thumb">
            </a>
            <a href="#/tests/{{test.id}}">
                {{ test.name }} 
            </a><br />

</form>
```

partials/test-detail.html (where none of the data are displayed and all checkmarks are false):

```
<div class="main">
 <img data-ng-src="{{mainImageUrl}}"/>
<h2>{{ test.name }}</h2>
 <p>{{ test.description }}</p>
    Customization: 
  <ul>
    <li>Test items: {{test.customization.items | checkmark }}</li>
    <li>Test duration: {{test.customization.duration |  checkmark }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

route provider in js/app.js:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
{$routeProvider
    .when('/tests',
     {templateUrl: 'partials/test-list.html', controller: 'ListController'})
    .when('/tests/:testId',
     {templateUrl: 'partials/test-detail.html', controller: 'TestDetailCtrl'})
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/tests'});
}]);
```

RESTful handling with js/services.js:

```
var appServices;
appServices = angular.module('appServices', ['ngResource']);
appServices.factory('Test', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource('tests/:testId.json', {}, {
    query: {method:'GET', params:{testId:'tests'}, isArray:true}
    });
}]);
```

controllers.js:

```
var ctr = angular.module('myApp.controller', []);
ctr.controller('ListController', ['$scope', 'Test', function ($scope, Test) 
  {$scope.tests = Test.query(); /*works*/
  $scope.orderProp = 'duration';}]); 

ctr.controller('TestDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Test', function($scope, $routeParams, Test) 
  {$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    $scope.test = Test.get({testId: $routeParams.testId}, function(test) {
      $scope.mainImageUrl = test.screenshots[0];
    });
    $scope.setImage = function(imageUrl) {
      $scope.mainImageUrl = imageUrl;
    };
    $scope.hello = function(name) {
      alert('Test ' + (name || 'works' + '!')); /*works*/
    }
   })}
 ]);
```

Example test-a.json:

```
[{
id: "test-a",
name: "test a",
description: "text ... bla",
"customization": {
    "items": true,
    "duration": false}
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mixing aspx partials with angular-arrays here.

Angular ng-repeat will work on client side only and will evaluate your scope.tests array when it finishes loading.

Your aspx partial (test-detail.html) will probably work server-side and will depend on you data-binding it with a container.

**Edit:** Your test-a.json looks strange... why is it encapsulated with brackets? (Why is it an array?) The partials/test-a.html is not made for arrays. Try this JSON (test-a.json):

```
{
id: "test-a",
name: "test a",
description: "text ... bla",
"customization": {
    "items": true,
    "duration": false}
}
```

Comment: okay it really was that simple - I spent two days on that and just didn't see it! Thanks Nils, I appreciate your help :)

Comment: No problem, I know the feeling ;-)